# How to turn on Wi-Fi Software radio status with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, wifi

-EDITED- Solved here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1698403/how-to-turn-on-or-off-wi-fi-software-radio-status-with-powershell

Any help how can I turn on/off the software radio status on Windows 11?
This is the status of my Wi-Fi:

```
Netsh WLAN show interfaces

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Killer Wireless-n/a/ac Wireless Network Adapter
    GUID                   : xx
    Physical address       : xx
    Interface type         : Primary
    State                  : disconnected
    Radio status           : Hardware On
                             Software Off

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

This is the setting in Windows 11:
[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/04/replace-netsh-with-windows-powershell-basic-network-cmdlets/

Comment: @lit no, `Enable-NetAdapter` or `Disable-NetAdapter` don't work, because that setting is not a network adapter but a Windows setting.

Comment: I note that this is a "Windows only" solution. It does not work with PowerShell Core.

Comment: @lit what does Windows only solution mean?

Comment: "Windows only solution" means that it only works on Microsoft Windows using "Windows PowerShell". The last "Windows PowerShell" was 5.1, released in 2016. It will not work on "PowerShell Core" (latest release 7.2)  which runs on MacOS, Linux, and Windows systems. http://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

Here's some PS code to do the trick:

```
#Disable Network?

Try {

        $NICs = Get-NetAdapter -Name * | 
                Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Up" -and
                              $_.InterfaceName -like "*wireless*"} |
         disable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$True
     }

Catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
       "Get-NetAdapter CmdLet NOT available."
}
```

Notes:

If you want to disable regardless of the Status eliminate the first test in the Where-Object clause.

If you don't want to confirm turning it off replace -Confirm:$True w/ -Confirm:$False.

This code will disable ALL wi-fi adapters but could be adjusted to do only select ones.

Comment: The answer for you is the same as for @lit because that command is for network adapter, the setting I am asking for is a global setting not for any specific interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this in a standard batch file:

```
    explorer ms-settings:network-wifi
    ping  localhost > nul
    :VBSDynamicBuild
    SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
    IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
    ECHO Set WshShell = 
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>>"%TempVBSFile%"
    ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}">>"%TempVBSFile%"
    ECHO WshShell.SendKeys " ">>"%TempVBSFile%"
    CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
```

It basically opens up the "System", "Network & internet" window and toggles the WiFi on/off button. Run the batch file once to toggle it to the other state, and run the batch file again to toggle it back. I use the ping to delay the running of the script until after the "Network & internet" window has opened.